# Kepler's law of periods question, application

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

I'm a year 12 student studying in Sydney Australia.

I would like to ask about a physics question which I'm currently troubled on. I have made several attempts of answering the question but no luck. Includes: Trying to sub the information into the [Kepler's 3rd law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion), which is  $r^3 / t^2 = GM/ 4\pi^2$.

Could someone please hint, or explain HOW this question can be answered as it would help me greatly.

> Geostationary satellites orbit with a radius of 42260km. Use this information to find the period of a satellite which orbits with a radius of 15000km.

Comment: Use the fact that Geo-stationary satellites have a period of 24 hours.

Comment: Oh yeah forgot about that. But could you elaborate with why there is two radius values and which one im suppose to use?

Comment: See that the RHS of your equation is a constant.So use the respective values of $r$ and $t$ for the two given situations.

Comment: Iam afraid i dont understand. I understand that the RHS is constant. But i dont understand the 'two given situations'.

Comment: From the first situation you know $r$ and $t$, so you can find the constant value of the RHS (of Earth). This will leave you with only one unknown in the second situation, its orbital period, which can be found using the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the first situation to find the value of $GM$ (you don't know the mass and you can avoid the use of the constant).

$$
GM=\frac{4π^2r^3}{t^2}
$$

As you have found this factor, you can use it to compute the time revolution of the second satellite. Also note that in the case of geostationary satellite, the period is about 24h (you may need a more exact value).

Comment: Why not directly set the left hand side of both equation equal to each other ($\frac{r_1^3}{t_1^2}=\frac{r_2^3}{t_2^2}$), since only $t_2$ is asked?